# where to start with z3950 and Java

Tags: jakarta-ee, z39.50

I'm writing Java web project, main goal is - searching in libraries with z39.50 protocol.(it's client not server)

I've found that there is ZOOM library. from this project born series of projects: JZKit, YAZ4J, JAFER.

I tried Yaz-client (in Windows), program works nice.
I didn't got how works Yaz4j.
and I liked Jafer, but I cant understand how to receive results in needed format...

I have googled, but information about z3950 in java is absence for me.
Where I can find more info about z3950 implementation in Java?

Comment: still I don't understand, where found tuts about how work with Jafer in client mode. Cause main feature for receiving results they uses XML and XLS, also they in some way tricky uses MODS format.

`// set schema on the factory to return records as mods format`
`factory.setRecordSchema("http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3");`

Comment: I've found that YAZ implementation in java, called - JZKit...

Comment: my head hurts, there is no clear solution for this protokol, all 'fresh' development was done in 2004 year, after that there is no more information about it :(

Comment: Note; http://www.k-int.com/jzkit is dead but http://www.k-int.com/products/jzkit seems to exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't looked at yaz4j for a while you should give it another go as the installation has been greatly simplified. For Windows, yaz4j is now bundled in the YAZ Windows installer (http://www.indexdata.com/yaz) and on Linux/OS X you can download the source tarball (http://www.indexdata.com/yaz4j) and compile it (check the README first).

Comment: Of cause  I look to yaz project! :) After intense correspondence with you, finally I compile yaz4j.dll and yaz4j.jar, in Windows environment. But I hit the wall with PATH in Windows and classpath in Eclipse. And project in Eclipse dosn't work ))) so I started explore Linux develop environment. After all I continue to dig in two directions, Windows and Linux. I have not won yet, and I learning a lot )))

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this example out (for JZKit):
http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hamish/3NI/tutor/topic67.html

Also here explains how to get DOM Document format:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/253861/probles-with-jzkit

Comment: Definitely it is new information which I have not seen, thanks for the links.

Comment: I gave up on JZKit because it makes heavy use of the spring application context. I don't use spring. So I attempted to you JAFER and was able to get a test working with:
http://www.jafer.org/source/wsvn/JAFER/trunk/src/org/jafer/test/TestClient.java  .. what format are you looking to use? My results are in MARC21 (default) so I was able to use the example to parse out info from the record and format it myself.

Comment: I'm also gave up with JZKit. Except 'spring' it uses 'maven' for build. With this pom.xml I couldn't build anything working unfortunately. Yaz4j is still developing. But I couldn't use it, because it uses native library yaz.cpp which should compile with provided pom.xml, but I couldn't do it at Windows.(there is long story about installing Windows Visual Studio and bunch of errors with installation it and after running it). Last time I was playing with Jaffer. With it I finally could connect to my local library. But I live in Russia, and cyrillic encoding vital for me.

Comment: so at first I need to recieve RUSMARC records, secondly at my step I could request only with english symbols (like "Java" & "Script"), hence I've got two problems for now. I make requests minimum with 2 parameters (author & title), whilst sometimes I need request with one search parameter. And I don't know how to make requests with Cyrillic symbols. When I try to do so, library server gives me zero results. But it's ok when I search with english symbols "Java" "Script". I guess it's somewhere with encodings.
So I dig into JAFFER sources. Yaz4j and JZKit are frozen for me for now.

Comment: In jafer, I've found where the bottleneck of only ascii symbols. Solution resides in Zebulun module. At ans1.ASN1OctetString methods set(byte octet_array[]) and set(String str) {... octets = str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");....}  So I take method set with byte array and give him my Cyrillic symbols in UTF-8 encoding